# want code in objective c

Tags: iphone

I've defined three strings as s1="@$100",s2="@$50",s3="@$150". now I want the total of three strings stored in S4="@$300" in which all the internal function methods are carriedout in single method in objective c code?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Comment: s1="@$100" is not correct, not for NSString, anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for string literal assignments you need `@""` not `"@"`. Second, to add up integers, you should use `ints`. And then you can convert that to a string using `stringWithFormat:`. But since you are starting with strings, simply convert those to integers, then add them up.

```
sFourString = [S4 intValue]; //Do this for all of your strings
```

Then add your ints together:

```
resultingValue = sFourString + allOtherInts;
```

And then convert `resultingValue` back to a string:

```
NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", resultingValue];
```

So putting it all together in one big statement:

```
NSString *completeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [S4 intValue] + [anotherString intValue]];
```